# How to test Disk IO on VMs with iozone?

Tags: performance, kvm, io, testing, iozone

I want to test the disk IO performance like read, write, random read, random write and so on both in physical machine and VMs (with aufs file system).
Also I want to test the throughput performance in a single bare machine and VMs running on the hypervisor to get how much performance loss in Virtual machine (KVM).

I used this command before, but it wasn't enough,and it just tested 1 process!
(you can see the output [here](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8136941150/Selection_031.png))

```
$ iozone -Mce -I -+r -r 256k -s 2g -f iozone_$i.dat$$ -i0 -i1 -i2
```

What command should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the `-t` switch you can specify how many writers you want `iozone` to make use of. From the [IOzone PDF](http://www.iozone.org/docs/IOzone_msword_98.pdf).

```
-t #
Run Iozone in a throughput mode. This option allows the user to specify how 
many threads or processes to have active during the measurement.
```

#### Example

```
$ ./iozone -i 0 -t 2

Children see throughput for  2 initial writers 1=  433194.53 KB/sec
Parent sees throughput for  2 initial writers   =    7372.12 KB/sec
Min throughput per process          =       0.00 KB/sec 
Max throughput per process          =  433194.53 KB/sec
Avg throughput per process          =  216597.27 KB/sec
Min xfer                    =       0.00 KB

Children see throughput for  2 rewriters    =  459924.70 KB/sec
Parent sees throughput for  2 rewriters     =   13049.40 KB/sec
Min throughput per process          =  225610.86 KB/sec 
Max throughput per process          =  234313.84 KB/sec
Avg throughput per process          =  229962.35 KB/sec
Min xfer                    =     488.00 KB
```

*excerpt - [10 iozone Examples for Disk I/O Performance Measurement on Linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/05/iozone-examples/)*

> To execute the iozone in throughput mode, use -t option. You should
>   also specify the number of threads that needs to be active during this
>   test.
>
> The following example will execute the iozone throughput test for
>   writes using 2 threads. Please note that you cannot combine -a option
>   with -t option.

Comment: Thanks, It works! I wrote this command: 
`iozone -Mce -I -t 4 -+r -r 256k -s 2g -F iozone_$i.dat$$ -i0 -i1 -i2`

Comment: @Mehrnaz - wonderful!